# Generate Antiforgery Token in Windows store app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, antiforgerytoken

I am calling a WebAPI from my windows store app. Issue here how can I generate Antiforgery token to pass with my request.

Please help. I want the replacement of below like we do in asp. Not AntiForgery is not available in Windows store app

```
public string TokenHeaderValue()
{
    string cookieToken, formToken;
    AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
    return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
}
```

Below is the ajax call to send parameters along with token and to get the response:-

$.ajax(
"{URL for Web Api Method}", 
{
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'id':'userName',
                'password':'userPassword',
  'Accept-Language':'en-US',
                'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
});

Vinod

Comment: Wouldn't bearer-tokens be more appropriate? Does your app have an embedded browser using auth cookies for your resources that also allows access to sites other than your own? If not, this is a non-problem.

Comment: I have to pass Antiforgery token to request like we do in asp

Comment: Then your Web API is not designed to be called from clients that are not part of the same web application. Change it to token based authentication - e.g. have a look at the VS 2013 Web API templates.